# Launch options on simulator

Tags: ios, push-notification, ios-simulator, payload

I wanna test push notifications payload into simulator.

Xcode under to below steps.

Edit schema -> Run -> Arguments -> Argument passed on launch.
[image]

Now, i need that payload on `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` of AppDelegate method.

Any suggestion or help much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.